# mongodriver order by ascending

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm using this driver https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/getting-started/quick-start/

```
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("blogs");
String text = "hey";
List<String> searched = new ArrayList<String>();
// MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find("posts").sort(ascendingorder).iterator()
```

blogs collection has multiples json with 1 variable

```
{
    "_id": "randomid"
    "posts": "hey my name is bob"
}, 

{
    "_id": "randomid"
    "posts": "a hey my name is bob"
},
```

I want to sort each json into a list from ascending order if the searched text is found in this example its "hey". All post containing "hey" in ascending order

for example the list above would be

```
searched = [
    { 
        "_id": "randomid"
        "posts": "a hey my name is bob"
    },

    {
        "_id": "randomid"
        "posts": "hey my name is bob"
    }

]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to query like this :

```
db.blogs.find({"posts": /.*hey.*/}).sort( { posts: -1 } )
```

Or

```
db.blogs.find({'posts': {'$regex': 'hey', '$options': 'i'}}).sort({ posts: -1 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Random ID will be a timestamp created by the mongodb. You can sort using that.

```
-1: descending order
 1: ascending order 

 You can query like this:
 myDoc = coll.find(finalQuery).sort(new BasicDBObject("_id", -1));
```

Comment: So in my case it would be `myDoc = coll.find(finalQuery).sort(new BasicDBObject("posts",1 ));` but what goes in finalQuery?

Comment: @timtimothy If you want to do any query you can use it else you can remove that finalQuery. BasicDBObject finalQuery = new BasicDBObject("posts", "something"); If you want to do any specific find operation, you can use this else use you find() which will give you all the results. Hope you understand!